# Exporting Screen Infinite Loading, MarkdownPDF by yzane

Tags: markdown, vscode-extensions

PDF is being created but the extension is showing exporting infinitely, What to do to auto close that exporting screen after creation of pdf?
[Infinite Exporting Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dR24.png)

I tried to Disable all installed extensions and re-enabled them, but still it doesn't solve the issue.